# In Howler.js how to play a sound only when another is not playing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, howler.js

I'm making an Arkanoid with HTML5 canvas. I've loaded the music and sounds and they are working fine.
My problem is, that sometimes when in my code I hit the ball with the paddle, it is detecting 2, 3 or more collisions, the sound plays 2, 3 or more times in that moment.

Here I have an example of the sound behaviour.

https://u.pomf.is/mgmhsq.webm  (In the second 16 happens, and in second 23 plays -once- just fine.)

Here is some of my code

```
sound = new Howl({
    urls: ['assets/sounds.mp3'],
    volume: 0.2,
    buffer: true,
    sprite: {
        die: [1120, 1010],      // 1.120 start, 1.010 duration
        laser: [12485, 290],    // 12.485 start, 0.290 duration
        vaushit: [16816, 770],  // 16.816 start, 0.770 duration
        brickhit: [18616, 770]  // 18.616 start, 0.770 duration
    },
    onload: function() {
        init(); // when every music or sound is loaded
    }
});
```

Then I have something like this. (Check last lines)

```
    if (hit.c) {
        // If hit checkings
        switch(result.d) {
            case "top":                                
                ball.y = paddle.y - ball.radius;
                ball.angle = -ball.angle;
                break;
            case "right":                              
                ball.x = paddle.x + paddle.width + ball.radius;
                ball.angle = ball.angle + Math.PI;
                break;
            case "left":                               
                ball.x = paddle.x - ball.radius;
                ball.angle = ball.angle + Math.PI;
                break;
        }
        // spin effect
        if (inputStates.right) {
            ball.angle *= (ball.angle < 0 ? 1 : 1.5);
        } else if (inputStates.left) {
            ball.angle *= (ball.angle > 0 ? 1 : 1.5);
        }
        sound.play('vaushit'); // here!!
    }
```

I would need something to check if the sound is currently playing.

I've checked this: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js

Maybe it has something to do with the `on: Call/set custom events. Multiple events can be added by calling this multiple times.`

I don't know how to use this method anyway! I hope you guys can shed a light on my problem.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the 2.0 beta (which is quite stable and close to being merged). It has a new .playing() method which sounds like what you want.

Comment: @JamesSimpson thanks man, I will look on to it as soon as I can